# How to only display date component in a timestamp column - Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-datetime

I have a Pandas Dataframe that has a timestamp column. I would like to display only the date portion of it and not the hh:mm:ss portion. I tried using to_datetime function but it did not remove the time component. Could anyone assist on this. Thanks

```
input date : 2018-05-03 07:20:17
date = pd.to_datetime(df["FileReceivedTime"], format="%Y%m%d%")
date

Output : 2018-05-03 07:20:17
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this:

```
dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
```

in

```
date = pd.to_datetime(df["FileReceivedTime"], format="%Y%m%d%").dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
```